# angularjs ng-view inside ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

using angular 1.2.10 with ngRoute, jquery 1.10.2 I have the following code in my index.html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div ng-include src="'partials/login/login.html'"></div>

    <div ng-if="isAuthenticated()">
        <div ng-view/>
    </div>
    <!--javascript files-->
</body>
```

The initial login page(not configured as a route), downloads all the needed javascript files, but after I login, and ng-if evaluates to true, I notice a bunch of XHRs fired off by jquery for all the javascript files in the browser console:

```
XHR finished loading: "http://myurl/jquery-1.10.2.min.js?_=1392752363272"
XHR finished loading: "http://myurl/angular.min.js?_=1392752363273"
XHR finished loading: "http://myurl/app.js?_=1392752363274"
...and so on
```

console reports that these XHRs are being executed from jquery.1.10.2:8706

Based on the documentation it appears that when ng-if evaluates to true the element is created and compiled at that time. I imagine this has something to with ng-view and ngRoute and how these are wired together but I wasn't able to glean from the documentation why this particular behavior is occurring.  If anyone could lend some insight into this behavior and/or if there is something fundamentally wrong with the approach I was trying to take it would be much appreciated.

Note:This behavior does not occur if I use replace ng-if with ng-show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said, `ng-if` does not render its contents if it evaluates to `false`.

You're better off creating a separate route for your login page which will redirect you once you've been authenticated.

Comment: thanks, I think having a dedicated route for login is a good idea as well and I will strive to implement it that way. Although, I am still curious as to why those XHRs are fired off.

Answer (score 0):

I think better way to design is to use routes for all the things,

Lets say user is not authenticated then route to login page, and subsequent requests check for  the authentication (by cookie or token ) and then redirect to login page if some thing fails.